# Booting Linux Mint from USB Drive

Tags: bootable

New linux user here...

I'm trying to boot my Windows 10 PC, to Linux Mint, via a USB Drive. I have to do some coding work for college, and I liked the linux operating system better. Since I'll only be using it for small projects, I elected a boot from USB would be my best option. I successfully did it using Rufus, and a Linux Mint Cinnamon thing I downloaded from the internet.

I set all my settings and what not, made a couple c++ files, downloaded emacs and gfortran through the terminal. Restart my laptop, boot it. Everything is gone. Nothing I did is really important but how do I keep everything from deleting? I would like all my data and files to stay on. Is there something I did wrong when creating the flash drive? Thanks for your help guys!

If you know how to solve this problem, can you walk me through setting up a new bootable USB to fix this problem??

Answer (score 0):

Where did you work? 
In `/home`?

You have two choices:

- Find your main system disk
  (if it’s a HDD, it will probably be `/dev/sda` or `/dev/sdb`)
  and mount it (e.g., on `/mnt`) and work there.
- Enable persistence on your USB drive.

Comment: Ok, going into more detail about the first option. I found /dev. In dev, there is sda, and sda[1-5], sdb, and sdb1. However none of these are directories. Should they be? I have an SSD. Second, how do you "mount it" and what does that mean? Once I mount it will anything I change be ok, or will only files saved in that directory be saved? Sorry for the barrage of questions. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently using Linux in an external hard-drive from 2 years from now, since I can't afford a laptop. Currently I use an SSD with Xubuntu, but I had used Mint too.

What you need is not so simple, it took me months of tries to understand what is going on:

1. You will need 3 things: A installation media. The media you will install it and a computer. So, if you will install the mint in the USB `A`, you will need to make an installer in a USB `B` to install in the fresh `A` USB.
2. You need to select your USB drive in the installation page.
3. You will need to prevent grub, a boot manager, to scan all your current drives, since **your current hard drives UUID's are different than the computer you will stick your USB in**, making an 'grub rescue' error.

The installation page looks like this, you need to select advanced installation for that:
[image]

That's it, currently this setup saves me, without it I can't even work or study (my college only have Windows D:<).

Fun fact, I'm sending this answer from my external hard drive, which I booted into my mom's laptop.